# Customize Search results in Enterprise search 2010

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, enterprise, ranking

I work with  SharePoint 2010 and I'm very new to the same. I've been assigned     the task of customizing the search center results to reflect entries of one particular subsite in our intranet at the top at all times. Any suggestions on how to go about getting this done? I will be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary way to do that is to set the subsite up as an authoritative source:

1. Go to Central Administration
2. Click Manage service applications (below Application Management)
3. Click your Search Service Application
4. Click Authoritative Pages (below Queries adn Results)
5. Add the URL of your important site in Most authoritative pages

Comment: Hi Per. Thanks so much for your response and pardon my late reply. The thing is i tried the exact same thing you have suggested and still didn't get the desired results. That's when i turned to this site . Is there another way to go about it? Or maybe i missed something in the previous technique? straightforward as it is